# includes with multiple levels of foreign tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Vacancies have matchings, matchings have rooms, rooms have messages

I need to get the vacancies that follow the specific criteria of a matching attribute and then filter them again based on wether they have messages from an employee.

```
Vacancy.created_this_week
.includes(:matchings, :rooms, :messages)
.where(matchings: {state: ["applied", "accepted", "denied"]})
.where(messages: {from_employee: false}.count
```

Although I get following:

```
Can't join 'Vacancy' to association named 'rooms'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I understand the association is based on a matching but how else would I get this to fit in one query since I need to filter out an amount of vacancies too?

**EDIT**

Based on an answer below I tried

```
.includes(matchings: { rooms: :messages })
```

Which gives me

```
Can't join 'Matching' to association named 'room'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Sanity check:

```
>> Matching.first.room.messages
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Comment: did you setup `has_many through`?

Answer (score 2):

Try nesting the includes in Hash format:

```
.includes(matchings: { rooms: :messages })
```

Comment: Can't join 'Matching' to association named 'rooms'; perhaps you misspelled it?
Tried with 'room' as well since it only has one room then I get the same error.
Sanity check: 
>> Matching.first.room.messages
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>